# Why changing the "if" condition give different answers when I use === instead of !==?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

**The function checks if array elements are same, if they are same it should return true.**

When I use the function below, it gives the correct result.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function isUniform(arr) {
  var store = arr[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== store) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(isUniform(arr));
```

But when I use the function like this i.e; **changing the *if* condition**, it returns false

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function isUniform(arr) {
  var store = arr[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === store) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;

}

console.log(isUniform(arr));
```

Comment: Both are returning true in snippets

Comment: try for different array elements. @SanchitPatiyal

Comment: Check answer given by @Luca . You'll understand what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your snippet is returning `true` if one of the next values are the same as `arr[0]`, see the below example:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1];

function isUniform(arr) {
  var store = arr[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === store) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;

}

console.log(isUniform(arr));
```

Here the function returns true as soon as the for loop starts, since `arr[0]` *is* `store`

What you should use is [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which checks if all elements match certain criteria:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1];
var arr2 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

function isUniform(arr) {
  return arr.every(e => e === arr[0]);
}

console.log(isUniform(arr));

console.log(isUniform(arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The firts loop is giving the rigth answer because the elements in the list are not the same, the problem with the second loops is that it checks each element in the list and when i found a element equals to the `array[0]` (in this case (`1`)) it will return true which can't be.

The second loops should be:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    function isUniform(arr) {
      var store = arr[0];
      var response = false;
    
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === store) {
          resonse = true;
          continue;
        }
        return response;
      }
      return response;
    
    }
console.log(isUniform(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause it will return true if the first element is the same. It won't check all elements while the second will return true if all elements are the same if one of the elements is not the same it returns false.

The probably shortest approach to this is:

```
 (new Set(array)).size === 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The second code snipped does not check if all elements are equal to `store`, it returns `true` if at least one is equal to `store`.

And the first one returns `false` if all of the elemens are not equal to `store`, and as of that `true` if all of them are equal to `store`, but to be previces it does not test if all elements equal `store` it's only a logical conclusion in this case.

Answer (score -2):

It returns true ... You can also consider doing...

```
arr.includes(arr[0]) // returns true
```

Comment: This will always return true (unless it's an array of objects)